# How to hide empty rows in a FullCalendar agenda view?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm using FullCalendar in agenda mode and would like to hide the empty time cells:

[image: http://joxi.ru/v29OR78C3jNM0r]

and the all-day line. Does anyone know how to do it right?

Comment: you can hide the allDay using https://fullcalendar.io/docs/allDaySlot , but it will be hidden in all cases, even when there are allDay events. Hiding the empty timeslots makes no sense, then it's not an agenda where people can clearly see the passage of time and what's free and what's busy. That's the whole point of the agenda view. If you just want a list of events without any kind of time-related layout, then use the "list" style views. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/list-view

Comment: Thank you! I would like the option "basic", if the time levels were not just a kind of" one under another", and that every available time in every day would be at the same level. This has already been implemented in agenda. It remains only to remove the empty lines.

Comment: Unfortunately I think, partly due to the way Fullcalendar renders the calendar as two separate overlaid tables of fixed size - one containing the time grid and one containing the events, this will not be achievable with significantly changing the source code or making a whole new view type.

Comment: Correct! That's why I'm asking for help. Maybe someone knows the solution...

Comment: The solution would be too big and complicated for an answer here. Take a look at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/custom-view-with-js and also the existing code for the agenda view in the fullCalendar source code in Github and you might appreciate the scale of the task - you have a lot to do to understand the structure before you can even start to write any code.